# Rendering issues with turtle module

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am having trouble with the python turtle class using IDLE.

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.12+
```

The turning functions left() and right() do not work properly. I tried running the following code, which I found here: https://michael0x2a.com/blog/turtle-examples, Example 4:

```
import turtle 

star = turtle.Turtle()

for i in range(50):
  star.forward(50)
  star.right(144)

turtle.done()
```

It does not lead to the expected output, which is a star. Instead you can see this:

[image: a straight horizontal line with three dots around it]

The function does work at 90 degrees. I can draw a rectangle. At every other angle, the turtle stops drawing. I also tried to adjust the resolution with setworldcoordinates(), without change,
and searched the documentation for python 2.7.13 (here: https://docs.python.org/2/search.html?q=turtle&check_keywords=yes&area=default), but could not find any particular directions. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I executed the code in spyder and it works. THis means the error is in the IDE and not in the code or in the dependencies coming from the IDE / on your machine installed

Comment: Also I do not get why the value for the loop must be so high. It looks like the drawer is repainting the lines a lot. Maybe you need to wait a little or change the number ?

Comment: I also tried it with only plotting a cracked line. Same problem. 90*n degree works, others don't. I also executed it from the command line. I am now installing spyder to try it. If it is a dependency issue, what could it be?  I am not getting any errors in the console.

Comment: The same error occurs in spyder, but it tells me, that qtconsole and nbconvert are missing, which are not in the standard repositories. And I don't really understand how a dependency problem could affect this function only partially.

Comment: Works for me using the IDLE that comes with Python 2.7.13 (on Windows).

Comment: Open a shell and type: "pip install nbconvert" and "pip install qtconsole" this may fix the problem. qtconsole is mainly for widgets etc. and may effect the rendering of the image

Comment: The spyder dialog disappeared but the problem persists.

Comment: I know this isn't of much help but your question reminds me of two similar ones, [Turtle graphics ..., lines that are not vertical or horizontal are not visible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42346847/turtle-graphics-on-ubuntu-16-10-lines-that-are-not-vertical-or-horizontal-are-n#comment71873634_42346847) and [Turtle will not draw angled lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36664329/turtle-will-not-draw-angled-lines).  Neither has an answer.

Comment: Since turtle is built on tkinter, this may be apropos [Python tkinter wont display diagonal lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38278420/python-tkinter-wont-display-diagonal-lines) and contains an answer.